# How to draw an image onto a PictureBox Image

Tags: c#, winforms, picturebox

I need to know how to draw more than one Image on a PictureBox's Image.

I have used this code but it doesn't work:

```
    private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(pictureBox2.Image);

Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bmp);

g.DrawImage(new Bitmap(@"C:\Users\Mena\Desktop\1.png"), new Point(182, 213));

pictureBox2.Image = bmp;
    }
```

Comment: You should dispose of your graphic object.  "it doesn't work" isn't very descriptive.  Your rectf variable is rather unnecessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With a few changes your code will work fine:

```
private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(pictureBox2.Image);

    // whatever your plans where, we don't know ;-)
    // RectangleF rectf = new RectangleF(640F, 1100F, 0, 0);

    Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bmp);

    // DrawImage needs an image, not a string
    g.DrawImage(new Bitmap(@"C:\Users\Mena\Desktop\1.png"), new Point(182, 213));

    // flush is for finishing write operations
    // dispose is the command to get rid of GDI elements:
    g.Dispose();

    pictureBox2.Image = bmp;
}
```

The recommended way to write it would be:

```
private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(pictureBox2.Image);
    using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bmp))
    {
        g.DrawImage(new Bitmap((@"C:\Users\Mena\Desktop\1.png"), new Point(182, 213));
    }
    pictureBox2.Image = bmp;
}
```