# C# - picturebox, graphics.DrawImage and picturebox.Image = null, why?

Tags: c#, winforms, graphics, picturebox

I'm trying to crop and resize an image in PictureBox1. My code:

```
//original image for eventually undo
undoImage = pictureBox1.BackgroundImage.Clone() as Image;
Bitmap sourceBitmap = new Bitmap(pictureBox1.BackgroundImage, pictureBox1.Width, pictureBox1.Height);
Graphics g = pictureBox2.CreateGraphics();
g.DrawImage(sourceBitmap, new Rectangle(0, 0, pictureBox2.Width, pictureBox2.Height), rectCropArea, GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
sourceBitmap.Dispose();
```

And it working properly on two `PictureBox`es. 
But `PictureBox2.Image`,`PictureBox2.BackgroundImage` (and any other including ErrorImage...) `= null`. 
I tried `PictureBox.DrawToBitmap`, and other, like `g.GetHdc()` found on google, but unsuccessful.

**My question:**
How do I properly copy the edited image from `PictureBox2` to `PictureBox1`?

Comment: You have to assign `PictureBox.Image` to be able to use it. Drawing using graphics doesn't generate an `Image` for you, so (I guess) it stays `null`. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24620810/1997232).

Comment: `undoImage = pictureBox1.BackgroundImage.Clone() as Image;` this is wrong. its (as Sinatr says) `.Image` not `.BackGroundImage`

Comment: `CreateGraphics` is volatile.  It's lifespan is limited to the scope in which it is used.  You need to be drawing in the appropriate `Paint` method(s).  And @Sinatr is correct...why wouldn't it be null?  You never assigned an `Image` object, you just drew on it through brute force.

Comment: `BackgroundImage` is type `Image`. This is not a problem

Comment: Do not Dispose() it *before* you are going to display it.  Dispose the old one you no longer need. probably stored in PictureBox2.Image

Answer (score -2):

Trivial solution:

```
undoImage = pictureBox1.BackgroundImage.Clone() as Image;
Bitmap sourceBitmap = new Bitmap(pictureBox1.BackgroundImage, pictureBox1.Width, pictureBox1.Height);
using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(sourceBitmap))
{
      g.DrawImage(sourceBitmap, new Rectangle(0, 0, pictureBox2.Width,pictureBox2.Height), rectCropArea, GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
}
pictureBox1.BackgroundImage = sourceBitmap;
```